# How to bind multiple keys on one button in mouseX (more in description)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, gaming, mouse-click

I am currently using Mouse X and I was wondering if you could bind two key clicks into one button. For instance, when I press the left mouse button I would like to input:

---

---Click real Left  Mouse button---

**Start Command**

Click "a"

Release "a"

Click "Left Mouse Button"

Release "Left Mouse Button"

**End Command**

---Release real Left Mouse button---

---

Alternately I could bind "a" to when I PRESS the Left Mouse Button, and then bind "Left Mouse Click" to when I RELEASE the Left Mouse Button but I don't know how to do that either :(

[Here](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) is the link to Mouse X for those willing to help :)

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would use AutoHotKey for this.

The script would be

```
LButton::
send a
MouseClick
```

Once AutoHotKey is installed, save this script with .ahk extension and run it on start up, or whenever you need it.

Noting your 'game' tag: I've found with some games that AutoHotKey is too quick. For example, Elite Dangerous doesn't register some key strokes when sent the way I showed above. If that occurs, you can slow the process like this:

```
LButton::
send {a down}
sleep 100
send {a up}
sleep 100
MouseClick, D
sleep 100
MouseClick, U
```